# Updating to Ruby 3.0.x with Rails: symbol not found in flat namespace '_RHASH_EMPTY_P'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apple-m1, rbenv, macos-monterey, ruby-3

Having issues upgrading my rails project on my M1 Mac related to Debase not compiling due to `symbol not found in flat namespace '_RHASH_EMPTY_P'`

OS: Monterey 12.0.1
Machine: Mac mini (m1, 2020)
Ruby version: 3.0.2
Rails: 6.1.4.1

I've tried removing Gemfile.lock and totally reinstalling brew/rbenv/rails.  The app runs successfully on the Ruby:3.0.2 docker image.

When I run `rails s`, I get the following stack trace:

```
﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿/Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': dlopen(/Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1/lib/debase_internals.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_RHASH_EMPTY_P' - /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1/lib/debase_internals.bundle (LoadError)
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1/lib/debase.rb:4:in `<main>'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:9:in `<main>'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler.rb:175:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/Documents/Development/hub/config/application.rb:20:in `<main>'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/Documents/Development/hub/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/josh/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/Documents/Development/hub/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

From I can tell, debase [isn't compatible yet](https://github.com/ruby-debug/debase/issues/94) with ruby 3, neither I see is well maintained like other similar gems. Personally, I'd move to [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) or at least [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).
Your other options I can see are removing the gem, downgrading to ruby 2.7 or simply contributing with a PR to fix debase and make it compatible with ruby 3.